# Inherit/Share User Federation in Keycloak

Tags: realm, keycloak

I have created a User Federation to our LDAP server in the Master realm.
So far, I have to create a new User Federation in every new realm I am creating.

Is there any possibility to inherit/share/copy the User Federation from Master realm to any other?
Or do I have create a new User Federation for every realm? (Which would be a lot of work).

Best,
Max

Comment: AFAIK realms are completely separate in Keycloak.

I'm curious: Why do you add more realms? What's the semantic of a realm in your case?

Comment: As of the documentation, Master realm is special and should only be used for admin purposes. So I have one realm for APIs and one for Web Application's. For both I will have different users and access rights. I thought that this is the correct way to use realms - could be that I am completely wrong.