# How to share configuration between realms in keycloak

Tags: keycloak

We are working with keycloak, In our application, we have different organizations and we created different realms for each organization in keycloak too.

Our requirement is each realm admin need to manage their users and roles (create the user and assign roles etc), but role creation should be restricted. Is there any possible solution to do this?

Please let know the answers to flowing questions,

1 Is there any possibility to inherit/share/copy the User Federation from the Master realm to any other? if not then what is the best practice to handle these types of requirements.

2 Is any options to disable some administration for realms (for Example, role creation need to block from realms except master)

Please see some similar questions

[Inherit/Share User Federation in Keycloak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51633774/inherit-share-user-federation-in-keycloak)

https://keycloak.discourse.group/t/shared-realms-configuration/3642

Thank you